# OpenEdge JSON with a extent propertry

Tags: json, object, openedge, progress-4gl, extent

I'm having trouble reading a JSON that has a extent[6] data property.
This is the JSON:

```
{  
    "SalesRep": [  
        {  
            "SalesRep": "BBB",  
            "RepName": "Brawn , Bubba B.",  
            "Region": "East",  
            "MonthQuota": [  
                1600,1648,1697,1748,1800,1854  
            ]  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

I want to read the second numerical value (extent[2]=1648).

This is my pgm:

```
myParser    = NEW ObjectModelParser( ).  
myConstruct = myParser:ParseFile("JsonRaro.json").  
myJsonObj2 = CAST(myJsonObj1:GetJsonArray("ttSalesRep"):GetJsonObject(1),JsonObject).  
MESSAGE  
    "2 " STRING( myJsonObj2:GetJsonText("RepName") ) SKIP /*result="2 Brawn , Bubba B."*/  
    "3 " STRING( myJsonObj2:GetJsonText("MonthQuota") ) SKIP /*result="
                                                          [1600,1648,1697,1748,1800,1854]"*/  
    "3a " STRING( myJsonObj2:GetJsonArray("MonthQuota"):GetJsonArray(2,1) ) SKIP /*ERROR*/  
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

[Message result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Jey.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to get the item from the array, not another array.

So this

```
 "3a " STRING( myJsonObj2:GetJsonArray("MonthQuota"):GetJsonArray(2,1) )
```

should be

```
 "3a " STRING( myJsonObj2:GetJsonArray("MonthQuota"):GetInteger(2) )
```

Comment: Tnk
Works very nice!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I see your are using a `JsonObject`, which can do the trick and is very flexible.

If the structure of the `json` is simple and is valid to map to a temp-table, you can use something like:

```
define temp-table ttSalesRep serialize-name "SalesRep"
  field SalesRep   as character
  field RepName    as character
  field Region     as character
  field MonthQuota as integer extent 12.  // twelve months

temp-table ttSalesRep:read-json("file", "JsonRaro.json", "empty").

find ttSalesRep.
display ttSalesRep.MonthQuota[2].
```

The downside is that you need to define field `MonthQuota` with a fixed extend number (but I guess 12 is enough).

Comment: Hi. I have been using the new Classes for a short time and they are very good. I am also combining them with HANDLE variables.

Comment: The only problem I have is that the "GetType" method tells me that "MonthQuota" is a JsonArray, which is correct. But the "Forcast" property also reports it as a JsonArray. But the way I should be parssed is not the same.

Comment: This is my complete JSON.
{  
    "ttSalesRep": [  
        {  
            "SalesRep": "BBB",  
            "RepName": "Brawn , Bubba B.",  
            "Region": "East",  
            "MonthQuota": [  
                1600,1648,1697,1748,1800,1854  
            ],  
            "Forcast": [  
                {  
                    "Month1": "Enero",  
                    "Amont1": 111.1  
                },  
                {  
                    "Month1": "Marzo",  
                    "Amont1": 111.2  
                }  
            ]  
        }  
    ]  
}

Comment: Do you know if there is any method or attribute with which I can differentiate "MonthQuota" from "Forcast"?

Comment: The 'MonthQuota' is an array with primitive values (decimal). While the 'Forecast' array contains JsonObjects.